# Write text on sphere surface SceneKit?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am wondering if there is a way to write text along a surface of a sphere object in SceneKit.

I know I put a texture on the surface and achieve this kind of effect if I have an image, but I want to know if I can just add text dynamically somehow over the surface of the sphere.

Any idea?

[image]

EDIT:

This works:

```
    let layer = CALayer()
    layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor

    var textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.frame = layer.bounds
    textLayer.fontSize = layer.bounds.size.height
    textLayer.string = "Test"
    textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentLeft
    textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    textLayer.display()
    layer.addSublayer(textLayer)

    let box = SCNBox(width: 10, height: 10, length: 10, chamferRadius: 0.5)
    let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
    box.firstMaterial?.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true
    boxNode.position = position

    box.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = layer

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use any `CALayer` as the contents of your `SCNMaterialProperty` :)

Comment: I tried to add a CALayer with a TextLayer in it and the box disappears... So, I am doing something wrong. Not sure what.

Comment: Ok, adding the background color (orange) now the layer is used as texture on the box, but I see no text yet.

Comment: You can also use a SpriteKit `SKScene` as a material property contents. Either way you may need to mess with the `contentsTransform` to get it to appear with the orientation/position you want.