# In SceneKit, putting a text label onto SCNGeometry or SCNBox

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm trying to put a simple text label onto one (hopefully all types) of built in SCNGeometry shapes as they move across the screen. The closest I have come to success is adding a CALayer with CATextLayer to a SCNBox via .firstMaterial.diffuse.contents, as [described in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387116/write-text-on-sphere-surface-scenekit).

BUT, the text is never readable. With a SCNBox of height 1.0: when the size of the layer.frame and textLayer.fontSize is 1.0, the text does not appear; as the frame and font size increase (not the box) the text appears blotchy, like in the image below; and when very large, the text appears as squiggly lines.

[image]

The following code is part of the method that spawns shapes:

```
    var geometry:SCNGeometry

    let layer = CALayer()
    layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 4, height: 4)
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    var textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.frame = layer.bounds
    textLayer.fontSize = layer.bounds.size.height
    textLayer.string = "Matilda"
    textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentLeft
    textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    textLayer.display()
    layer.addSublayer(textLayer)

    let geometry = SCNBox(width: 1.0,
                          height: 1.0, 
                          length: 3.0,
                          chamferRadius: 0.0)

    geometry.firstMaterial?.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true
    geometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = layer

    let geometryNode = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
    geometryNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)

    scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(geometryNode)
```

Comment: Why is the layer size 4 by 4 points? That seem too small to contain legible text to me.

Comment: yes, but the SCNBox is height 1.0, length 3, and appears a good size on screen; and if I make the layer size larger, then the text appears as long illegible lines

Comment: The dimensions of the box sides and the layer are not comparable. In other words: 1 unit of measure for the box’s side is not the same length as 1 unit of measure for the layer that’s used as a texture.

Comment: Thanks David.  So I set a much larger layer.frame height: 50, which appears the same unit of measure as layer.bounds.size.height, AND a slighly smaller height value for fontSize, and now it is working. If you put "layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50)" as the answer, I'd accept it gladly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by David R., the units of the box size is not the same as the units of the frame size.

It worked after adjusting the frame to (and optimising SCNBox size):

```
layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50)
```